# Why table tr hover effect doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Can anyone suggest about the `table` hover effect? See the image:

[image]

When I hover `tr`, this image style that blue border needed. How to get this output?

https://jsfiddle.net/tamilselvancst/s9umr8fz/3/

Comment: add tr:hover .tr-hover {
  display: block;background-color:yellow(any)
}

Comment: hey selvan... its better to add your code to fiddle, So that is can be easy to solve

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @GaneshPutta: I attached my code in fiddle.

Comment: @Huelfe: I want hover effect in that blue border shown in image.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) you should read the most trivial English spelling problems, to improve your post quality.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
tr:hover td {
   border: 1px solid #2795ee;
   background-color: #8eb2d2;
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s9umr8fz/4/

You can also give, or a combination if you only need bottom border:

```
tr:hover {
   background-color: #8eb2d2;
}
tr:hover td {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #2795ee;
}
```

The point to note is border does not work on a tr. Hence it will have to be given to the td element instead.

You can give the blue as required or any other colour for that matter. These colour codes may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table tr:hover{
background:red;
}
.img-table tr:hover{
 background-image: url(http://img.mynet.com/ha2/tayyip.jpg);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr height="100">
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
<table style="width:100%" class="img-table">
  <tr height="100">
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I'll Give You Two Examples Try This......